# python3: Forcing utf-8 for stdout/stderr without externally setting PYTHONIOENCODING?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, exec

I'm using `python3`, and I want my program to utilize `utf-8` for `stdout` and `stderr` without my having to set the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to `utf-8` outside of the python program.

In other words, I want the choice of forcing `utf-8` output to be contained within the python program itself, no matter what setting of `PYTHONIOENCODING` or lack thereof might have been specified in the invoker's environment.

The only python3-specific way to accomplish this that I've figured out so far is to start the program as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6                                                                                                            

import os
import sys
if os.environ.get('PYTHONIOENCODING', '').lower() != 'utf-8':
    os.environ['PYTHONIOENCODING'] = 'utf-8'
    sys.exit(os.execl(
        sys.executable, 
        os.path.basename(sys.executable), 
        *sys.argv
    ))

# Remainder of my program ...
```

Ideally, I'd like to implement this without having to re-exec the python3 interpreter, but I fear that I'm probably out of luck.

Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

ADDENDUM:

Per the comments in the answer, below, I tried the following, but it doesn't print anything ...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
open(sys.stdout.buffer.fileno(), 'w', encoding='utf8')
open(sys.stderr.buffer.fileno(), 'w', encoding='utf8')
print('Seems to be working')
sys.exit(0)
```

I also tried `utf-8` (with the hyphen), and it doesn't print anything, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And now I understand better what lenz suggested, and I figured out the answer:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import os
import sys
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.buffer.fileno(), 'w', encoding='utf8')
sys.stderr = os.fdopen(sys.stderr.buffer.fileno(), 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

Answer (score 1):

Some people suggest

```
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("UTF-8")(sys.stdout)
```

Others say that may break some libraries.

Comment: In Python 3 you need to call the writer factory on `sys.stdout.buffer`, the binary stream underlying the `TextIOWrapper` that `sys.stdout` defaults to.

Comment: I know that the stream handler returned by `codecs.getreader` has limited functionality compared to `io.TextIOWrapper`; the same is probably true for `getwriter` – I'm talking about methods like `seek`, `tell`, `truncate` etc. If you need a fully-fledged `TextIOWrapper`, you can call `open(sys.stdout.buffer.fileno(), 'w', encoding='utf8')`.

Comment: See my `ADDENDUM` to my original question, above. This doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: ... but now I figured out what you meant. See my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As of Python 3.7, TextIOWrapper has `reconfigure` method for you:

```py
sys.stdin.reconfigure(encoding="utf-8")
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding="utf-8")
sys.stderr.reconfigure(encoding="utf-8")
```